# Memo fields display strings with strange characters instead of the actual text, why?

Tags: ms-access

I'm very new to Microsoft Access and I'm working with some old files created with MS Access 97.

What I'm wondering is:

- Why would a Memo field display a string filled with strange characters instead of the actual text? (some guesses: 1. Some sort of compression is in effect. 2. The text is encrypted. 3. The text is encoded in a different encoding then the one being used to display the text.)

Example string (from an actual file):

> "©{aÉi~¬|ù(~tKÃ!"

And if there is a definite reason, how would I convert it to the actual text?

P.S. It's only these memo fields that are giving me trouble, all other fields display readable information.

Comment: do you know what the text should be

Comment: Yes, that particular string should be: `fl.\nmanual` (or at least approximately, there could be some space characters and the \n could be some other type of new line character)

Comment: what are you using to work with these files?

Comment: I'm using MS Access 97 (a bit old, but I decided to just use the app the files were created with).

Comment: my guess would be the app that created them got it slightly wrong so access is not getting the correct data, i've been using MDBPlus recently to look at older access files http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm

Comment: MDBPlus shows the same strange value. :/

Comment: Happened to me once when I [Grouped By a Memo filed](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=278505). Please read more [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html).

Comment: Looks encrypted to me - but we can only guess. Perhaps you can find some hints from the VBA code in the mdb. Or do these files only contain tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to compare Memo fields (as in sorting, or WHERE, Join on a field, or agrigating), they may be truncated.
Please see [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html)